# What is the difference between the split_view and the lazy_split_view in C++?

Tags: c++, std-ranges, c++23

I have read the latest draft where `lazy_split_view` is added.

But later on, I realized that `split_view` was renamed into `lazy_split_view`, and the `split_view` was renewed.

`libstdc++` also recently implemented this by using `GCC Trunk` version https://godbolt.org/z/9qG5T9n5h

I have a simple naive program here that shows the usage of two views, but I can't see their differences:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <ranges>

int main(){

    std::string str { "one two three  four" };

    for (auto word : str | std::views::split(' ')) {
        for (char ch : word)
            std::cout << ch;
        std::cout << '.';
    }

    std::cout << '\n';

    for (auto word : str | std::views::lazy_split(' ')) {
        for (char ch : word)
            std::cout << ch;
        std::cout << '.';
    }

}
```

Output:

```cpp
one.two.three..four.
one.two.three..four.
```

until I've noticed the differences when using as `std::span<const char>` for both views.

In the first one: `std::views::split`:

```cpp
for (std::span<const char> word : str | std::views::split(' '))
```

the compiler accepts my code.

While in the second one: `std::views::lazy_split`

```cpp
for (std::span<const char> word : str | std::views::lazy_split(' '))
```

throws compilation errors.

I know there will be differences between these two, but I can't easily spot them.
Is this a defect report in C++20 or a new feature in C++23 (with changes), or both?

Comment: In general [lazy evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_evaluation#:~:text=In%20programming%20language%20theory,%20lazy,avoids%20repeated%20evaluations%20(sharing).) happens on demand _as you need it_. In other words, lazy computes only when you read the value, in contrast to when you create that value.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've looked at the relevant paper ([P2210R2](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2021/p2210r2.html) from Barry Revzin) and `split_view` has been renamed to `lazy_split_view`. The new `split_view` is different in that it provides you with a different result type that preserves the category of the source range.

For example, our string `str` is a contiguous range, so `split` will yield a contiguous subrange. Previously it would only give you a forward range. This can be bad if you try to do multi-pass operations or get the address to the underlying storage.

From the example of the paper:

```
std::string str = "1.2.3.4";
auto ints = str 
    | std::views::split('.')
    | std::views::transform([](auto v){
        int i = 0;
        std::from_chars(v.data(), v.data() + v.size(), i);
        return i;
    });
```

will work now, but

```
std::string str = "1.2.3.4";
auto ints = str 
    | std::views::lazy_split('.')
    | std::views::transform([](auto v){
        int i = 0;
        // v.data() doesn't exist
        std::from_chars(v.data(), v.data() + v.size(), i);
        return i;
    });
```

won't because the range `v` is only a forward range, which doesn't provide a `data()` member.

### Original Answer

I was under the impression that `split` must be lazy as well (laziness was one of the selling points of the ranges proposal after all), so I made a little [experiment](https://godbolt.org/z/j73hd9vxW):

```
struct CallCount{
    int i = 0;

    auto operator()(auto c) {
        i++;
        return c;
    }

    ~CallCount(){
        if (i > 0) // there are a lot of copies made when the range is constructed
            std::cout << "number of calls: " << i << "\n";
    }
};


int main() {
    
    std::string str = "1 3 5 7 9 1";

    std::cout << "split_view:\n";

    for (auto word : str | std::views::transform(CallCount{}) | std::views::split(' ') | std::views::take(2)) {
    }

    std::cout << "lazy_split_view:\n";

    for (auto word : str | std::views::transform(CallCount{}) | std::views::lazy_split(' ') | std::views::take(2)) {
    }    
}
```

This code prints (note that the `transform` operates on each char in the string):

```
split_view:
number of calls: 6
lazy_split_view:
number of calls: 4
```

So what happens?

Indeed, both views are lazy. But there are differences in their laziness. The `transform` that I put in front of `split` just counts how many times it has been called. As it turns out `split` computes the **next** item eagerly, while `lazy_split` stops as soon as it hits the whitespace after the **current** item.

You can see that the string `str` consists of numbers that also mark their char index (starting at 1). The `take(2)` should stop the loop after we've seen '3' in `str`. And indeed `lazy_split` stops at the whitespace after '3', but `split` stops at the whitespace after '5'.

This esentially means that `split` fetches its next item eagerly instead of lazy. This difference probably shouldn't matter most of the time but it can impact performance critical code.

I don't know whether that was the reason for this change (I haven't read the paper).